# Ignore second monitor workspaces

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I recently switched from Mint to Ubuntu. In Mint I had an option to only use my primary monitor for workspaces. I can't seem to replicate that in Ubuntu. I am fairly new to Linux.

I almost always got a virtual machine running with Netflix or something on it, and I would like to keep watching when I swap workspaces.

I tried: 
Twin view in the nVidia settings, but I can't get the configure button to show. Image of said screen:
[image: nVidia Configure screen]

"Always on visible workspace" but it gets reverted when i host+f to maximize.

Unity tweak tool and the appearance tab, but the option isn't there. Screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/iL9OjLo]

CompizConfig had no apparent option for workspaces either.

In Dconf and Gconf had no dice either.

I apologize if this has been asked many times before, I just can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

Specs:

- Core i7 2600k
- Nvidia GTX 580
- 16GB RAM

Comment: this is such a great question, and no possible answers yet? Did you get this sorted out?